# Measure current through a stepper motor coil

Tags: current-measurement, waveform, stepper-driver

I have a [TB6600](http://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/ap-en/product/linear/motordriver/detail.TB6600HG.html) stepper motor driver and I wanted to measure and observe the current through a single phase (as shown on pg. 23 of the data sheet) of the connected stepper motor on an oscilloscope. The priority is to observe the waveforms shapes first and then measure the actual current flowing through each coil of the motor. I tried measuring the voltage drop across the current sense resistors Nfa and Nfb but that gave me very weird waveforms. Would measuring the waveforms directly across the coil and then dividing this voltage by the coil resistance be the right way to do this?

**EDIT:** Here are some waveforms captured across the sense resistor of one phase. These were taken when the stepping frequency was around 9 KHz and the stepping resolution was 1/16 micro steps. I'm not sure what to make of these.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "*but that gave me very weird waveforms*". How weird is very weird? What waveform did you expect? - I bet that the "very weird waveform" you saw was the real deal.

Comment: I was expecting to see a near approximation of a sinusoidal wave instead what I saw was inter spaced spikes.

Comment: pics or it didnt happen

Comment: You can't measure the current across something!

Comment: @LeonHeller maybe I didn’t word it properly. I meant to say I wanted to measure the current through the coil by measuring the voltage “across” it and then dividing by the coil resistance.

Comment: _"Would measuring the waveforms directly across the coil and then dividing this voltage by the coil resistance be the right way to do this?"_ Definitly not!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That waveform that you have presented looks like what I'd expect for the current through one coil of a stepper motor in action. Nothing weird here.

If you know the voltage across Nfa and you want to find the current through Nfa which is the same current that is flowing through the coil that is in series with Nfa. Then all you have to do is divide the measured voltage by the resistance of Nfa. Do the same thing for Nfb.

You do **not** want to divide by the resistance of the coil, or inductance. It has nothing to do with your measurement. You are measuring across Nfa/Nfb and Nfa/Nfb alone.

---

So for clarity, in case my words are going in through one ear and out the other.

\$I_{coil(a)}=I_{Nfa}=\dfrac{V_{Nfa}}{R_{Nfa}}\$

\$I_{coil(b)}=I_{Nfb}=\dfrac{V_{Nfb}}{R_{Nfb}}\$

If you do not know the value of \$R_{Nfa}\$ or \$R_{Nfb}\$, then grab a multimeter and measure it.

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't they look like a sine wave? Especially since its configured at 1/16 micro steps?

Comment: @electrophile No, for three reasons. (1), you are only measuring the legs of the H-bridge. So you will only see the current that is passing down through ground. You are not receiving the entire story. (2) When current is flowing through the inductor and you want to reduce it then you can activate the two bottom transistors to let the current rotate in a loop. Or the top transistors. Or you just reverse polarity entirely. There are **tons of ways** to control an H-bridge. The one that is used probably has some pros that are better than other designs. (3) doesn't have to be a sine wave.